# Concatenate specific fields in current row in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to have a cell in a sheet that all it does is concatenate some fields of the row I'm working on?

**Example:**

`A2` cell shows concatenated values of `row 4` cells `C4 and E4` (which is the row I'm currently working on). If I start working on `row 5`, than `A2` cell will show concatenated values of `C5 and E5` cells. and so on...

Here's a gif to visually ilustraste what I need...

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible, because the Excel object model gives you a hook on worksheet selection change - look into the `SheetSelectionChange` event of the `ThisWorkbook` module; the `Target` parameter contains the selected cell, so you can build whatever output you want in A2. Your question isn't specific enough to be on-topic on this site though; *don't ask if it's possible, try it instead*, and tell us about exactly what you're stumped on, show us what error you're getting, where in your code, give us a [mcve] so we can replicate the bug without having the whole entire workbook at home. Cheers!

Comment: You'll need VBA. [This blog](https://teylyn.com/2010/08/22/let-your-fingers-do-the-walking-blog/) has a similar approach for a chart. You can re-use the code and construct a formula instead of a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using the Worksheet SelectionChange Event. Learn my code below...!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Range("A1")
    Const sumRow = 3

    Set r = Range(Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, sumRow).Address)

    myRange = conCatRangeValue(r)
End Sub

Private Function conCatRangeValue( _
    targetRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal sep As String = " ") As String

    Dim r As Range
    Dim result As String
    For Each r In targetRange
        result = result + sep + r.Value
    Next r

    conCatRangeValue = result
End Function
```

Try it and modify it to meet your need.

Comment: Download the workbook that I've created with that code here 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgJ535NvXxIBkxp6lcefyJmC_pwF